# How to display the same author name when it has different forms in more than one entry in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, abnt

I have three entries from the same author, but each entry has a different form of his name:

> Eduardo Monteiro
>
> Eduardo Henrique Soares Monteiro
>
> Eduardo H. S. Monteiro

I would like to preserve in my bib file how the name appears in each article, but I would like to display in my paper only one form. I thought the field shortauthor would do that for me, but it didn't work. The problem is if I use as it is, in the text each entry is treated as a different author:

> (Eduardo H. S. MONTEIRO, 2000; E. MONTEIRO, 2006; Eduardo Henrique Soares MONTEIRO, 2011)

If I use the shortauthor field:

> (MONTEIRO, 2000; MONTEIRO, 2006; MONTEIRO, 2011)

And in the references:

> MONTEIRO, Eduardo. [...]
>
> MONTEIRO, Eduardo H. S. [...]
>
> MONTEIRO, Eduardo Henrique Soares. [...]

What I would like to know is if there is a way to preserve in my bib file the name as it appears in each article but display only one form, and be trated as the same author, like this:

In the text:

> (MONTEIRO, 2000; 2006; 2011)

In the references

> MONTEIRO, Eduardo. [...]
>
> ______. [...]
>
> ______. [...]

I'm using biblatex-abnt.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=abnt,
    ittitles
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\setlength\parindent{0cm}

\begin{document}

\cite{Monteiro2000, Monteiro2006, Monteiro2011}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}

@Thesis{Monteiro2000,
  author       = {Eduardo H. S. Monteiro},
  title        = {Henrique Oswald (1852-1931)},
  type         = {Tese de Doutorado},
  institution  = {Université Paris-Sobonne},
  year         = {2000},
  subtitle     = {un compositeur brésilien audélà du natiomalisme musical l'exemple de sa musique de chambre avec piano},
  location     = {Paris},
  eventyear    = {2000},
}

@Article{Monteiro2006,
  author       = {Eduardo Monteiro},
  title        = {Henrique Oswald e os Românticos Brasileiros},
  journaltitle = {Textos do Brasil},
  date         = {2006-04-10},
  pages        = {68-71},
  url          = {http://dc.itamaraty.gov.br/imagens-e-textos/revista-textos-do-brasil/portugues/edicao-numero-12},
  urldate      = {2017-03-08},
  edition      = {12},
  location     = {Brasília},
  publisher    = {Departamento Cultural do Ministério das Relações Exteriores},
  subtitle     = {em busca do tempo perdido},
}

@Article{Monteiro2011,
  author       = {Eduardo Henrique Soares Monteiro},
  title        = {Por uma nova contextualização da obra de Henrique Oswald},
  journal      = {OPUS - Revista Eletrônica da ANPPOM},
  year         = {2011},
  pages        = {9-42},
  url          = {http://www.anppom.com.br/revista/index.php/opus/article/view/198},
  volume       = {17},
  number       = {2},
  issn         = {1517-7017},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Even though your question is reasonably clear without it, please consider adding an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) to your question. That way we can see what exactly you have tried and can get started much more easily.

Comment: -1 pt for `\setlength\parindent{0cm}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Biber's sourcemapping to normalise the names for you

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[foreach={author, editor, translator}]{
      \step[fieldsource=\regexp{$MAPLOOP},
            match=\regexp{Eduardo\s+(H.\s+S.|Henrique\s+Soares)+\s*Monteiro},
            replace={Eduardo Monteiro}]
    }
  }
}
```

This normalises all versions you mentioned caught by regex to 'Eduardo Monteiro' in the fields `author`, `editor` and `translator`. You can easily add more name fields in the `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But, by your answer I understand that there isn't only a field I could use to replace the author name. This code is new to me (I'm using Latex for a few months yet), but I know what regex is. I only have to learn how to use Biber.

Comment: @FilipeFonseca If I get you right, then you are correct. `shortauthor` is only considered for citations, so it won't help you in the bibliography. And `sortname` only does sorting, so that is no good either. This means that the only thing that can help us is a manipulation of the real `author` field. This has the advantage that everything happens automatically - you won't need to change your `.bib` file a bit.

Comment: @FilipeFonseca By 'I only have to learn how to use Biber' do you mean to say that you don't know where to put the code? Or was that just a general remark? I forgot to mention that you have to put the code into the document preamble, but I hope that was clear.

Comment: I mean I don't know what Biber is and how to use it. I have to learn it yet, read the documentation, etc, to be able to do what you suggested, for example, without having to copy someone's code. But I knew I have to put this code in the preamble and it worked here. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FilipeFonseca Ah, good to hear that it worked for you. If you think that this answer answered your question, you can accept it using the green arrow on the top left of the answer to indicate that this answered your question.